# fstream read behavior upon hitting eof

Tags: c++, c++11

1.What happens if fstream::read() hits eof before reading enough characters of length field?

2.How can I tell how many characters have been read in this case?

Thanks

```
while(in_file.read(buffer, buffer_length)){
//what happens if eof not at the end of size buffer_length
            temp = sendto(sender_socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, NULL, 0); 
            byte_count += temp;
            msg_count ++;
}
```

What I'm trying to do here is read in fixed length of a file and send to sender_socket however for the last message the buffer is most likely unfilled, instead of sizeof(buffer) how do I determine the size I'm sending. The files will be in binary form.

Comment: What does the documentation say on the topic? Why is this tagged [tag:c]?

Comment: RTFM. If your documentation doesn't cover this you need new documentation.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/):

> If the input sequence runs out of characters to extract (i.e., the end-of-file is reached) before `n` characters have been successfully read, the array pointed to by `s` contains all the characters read until that point, and both the `eofbit` and `failbit` flags are set for the stream.
>   ...
>   The number of characters successfully read and stored by this function can be accessed by calling member `gcount`.

So you can do:

```
while(in_file.read(buffer, buffer_length)){
    temp = sendto(sender_socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, NULL, 0); 
    byte_count += temp;
    msg_count ++;
}
streamcount n = in_file.gcount();
if (n > 0) { // read a partial buffer
    temp = sendto(sender_socket, buffer, n, 0, NULL, 0);
    byte_count += temp;
    msg_count++;
}
```

Comment: thanks, what is "streamcount"? can I do int n = in_file.gcount()?

Comment: Read the documentation of `gcount`. `streamcount` is a typedef for the integer type that it returns.

Comment: The more you provide free handouts, the less likely your repeated invitations to "read the documentation" will _ever_ be heeded.